# Is it possible to make a WPF modaless view to become a modal one?

Tags: wpf, prism, modal-dialog, region-management

I'm using Prism pop-up region and the popup is modaless. When I tried to change Prism sample codes to replace `.Show()` by `.ShowDialog()` command, the codes become unstable. So, I need to keep the current codes intact and think of a work-around: change to modaless mode to be modal mode.

I don't know how to do that and/or if that is possible or not. Please share if you know how to. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "the code becomes unstable"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Stock Trader Reference Implementation and the RegionPopupBehavior and the DialogActivationBehavior then yes you can.  You should only have to change the PrepareContentDialog method of the DialogActivation behavior method from Show() to ShowDialog().

The reference implementation example is not very robust, and I ran into problems creating a more robust popup with the sample code.  However, once you tweak the behaviors, you can get it working well.

If you provide more details about your specific problem, I may be able to provide more help.